# Repeated BSOD After Windows Reinstall

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod

I run FSX in Windows 7 64 bit environment. I needed to reinstall windows and after the reinstall I get multiple BSOD events.

**Specs:**

Geforce GTX 660 8 gig RAM, Core I5 overclocked to 4.0 ghz.

---

Looked at DMP Files and see no recurring pattern:

> Dump Headers
>   090713-7051-01.dmp  9/7/2013 8:04:46 PM PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA 0x00000050  fffff8e0`0b2d4b48   00000000`00000000   fffff880`016f47c9   00000000`00000005   bowser.sys  bowser.sys+43b8850                  x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75b80                  C:\Windows\Minidump\090713-7051-01.dmp  4   15  7601    303,168 9/7/2013 8:05:19 PM
>
> 090713-5881-01.dmp 9/7/2013 7:07:32 PM SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION    0x0000003b  00000000`c0000005   fffff960`000cd99a   fffff880`08a1ff60   00000000`00000000   srv.sys srv.sys+1365f60                 x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75b80                  C:\Windows\Minidump\090713-5881-01.dmp  4   15  7601    303,168 9/7/2013 7:08:31 PM
>
> 090713-7410-01.dmp 9/7/2013 7:02:20 PM DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL   0x000000d1  fffffa02`0a79a880   00000000`00000002   00000000`00000000   fffff880`04fa39ca   raspptp.sys raspptp.sys+114d9ca                 x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75b80                  C:\Windows\Minidump\090713-7410-01.dmp  4   15  7601    303,168 9/7/2013 7:02:52 PM
>
> 090713-7722-01.dmp 9/7/2013 3:33:49 PM PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA 0x00000050  fffff940`c0737060   00000000`00000000   fffff960`000c56b0   00000000`00000005   dxgmms1.sys dxgmms1.sys+43188f0                 x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75b80                  C:\Windows\Minidump\090713-7722-01.dmp  4   15  7601    303,168 9/7/2013 3:34:48 PM
>
> 090713-7612-01.dmp 9/7/2013 3:08:23 PM SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION    0x0000003b  00000000`c000001d   fffff800`030bd1c2   fffff880`08026f20   00000000`00000000   discache.sys    discache.sys+4e4ef20                    x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75b80                  C:\Windows\Minidump\090713-7612-01.dmp  4   15  7601    303,168 9/7/2013 3:09:26 PM
>
> 090713-7831-01.dmp 9/7/2013 1:58:07 PM IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL  0x0000000a  fffffa80`c62c5e28   00000000`00000002   00000000`00000000   fffff800`031091cb   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+75b80  NT Kernel & System  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.18205 (win7sp1_gdr.130708-1532)    x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75b80                  C:\Windows\Minidump\090713-7831-01.dmp  4   15  7601    303,168 9/7/2013 1:59:10 PM
>
> 090713-8049-01.dmp 9/7/2013 1:37:02 PM PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA 0x00000050  fffff820`1658dfe8   00000000`00000000   fffff800`03388a42   00000000`00000005   nvlddmkm.sys    nvlddmkm.sys+1de4130                    x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75b80                  C:\Windows\Minidump\090713-8049-01.dmp  4   15  7601    303,168 9/7/2013 1:38:01 PM
>
> 090713-8034-01.dmp 9/7/2013 12:06:18 PM    PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA 0x00000050  fffff8e0`084bb790   00000000`00000000   fffff800`03386187   00000000`00000005   discache.sys    discache.sys+5c54720                    x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75b80                  C:\Windows\Minidump\090713-8034-01.dmp  4   15  7601    303,168 9/7/2013 12:07:18 PM
>
> 090713-8096-01.dmp 9/7/2013 11:24:13 AM    IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL  0x0000000a  fffffa82`0a8a2f4e   00000000`00000002   00000000`00000000   fffff800`030d2ff4   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+75b80  NT Kernel & System  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.18205 (win7sp1_gdr.130708-1532)    x64 ntoskrnl.exe+75b80                  C:\Windows\Minidump\090713-8096-01.dmp  4   15  7601    303,168 9/7/2013 11:25:17 AM

Do not know how to upload the DMP files here

Comment: Do the problems persist if you do not overclock? Is it warmer than before?

Comment: I was overclocked to 4.3 before I re installed windows backed off to 4.0 when kept getting BSOD. My temperature monitors do not show a high temp

Comment: disable the OC completely and look if this fixes it. You can upload the dmp files (compressed into 1 zip) to your SkyDrive/Dropbox account and post a link here.

Comment: I have been tied up with other events will do so soon.